# Login page first before being able to download a file

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.NET and web application developing.  What I'm trying to implement is, I am storing a file on the web server and is supposed to give the link of the file to the user for them to download the file.  The link and the "downloading" process is easy but I wanted to make it more secure like having the link go through the login page, then the user will enter his/her credentials, if success, then the file will be automatically downloaded.

Does anyone know how where should I start or what is the name of this kind of method/processing for me to be able to start my research.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the download page's Page_Load method check `Session["IsLoggedIn"]` or `Session["LoggedInUserId"]` where these session variables is set at your login page's `BttnLogin_Click` method.

Login.aspx

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TxtBxUserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="BttnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" OnClick="BttnLogin_Click"/>
```

Login.aspx.cs

```
protected void BttLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // guarantee that a user with the given username(TxtBxUserName.Text) exist
    // find the id of the user
    Session["LoggedInUserId"] = userId;
    //or just do
    Session["IsLoggedIn"] = 1;// I use 0 and 1 for this kind of job      
}
```

Don't forget you need to set `0` to `Session["IsLoggedIn"]` and set `-1`(for an invalid id) to `Session["LoggedInUserId"]`.

Now when you download page loads, just check one of these session variables.If the login condition is met then let the user download that file if not redirect to login page like below;

```
if(Session["IsLoggedIn"].ToString() == "1")
{
    // download
}
else
{
    Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am managing to downloading of file through javascript, question is, is this the appropriate method to implement this?  The javascript is something like this:`code`function downloadFile() {
    var s = queryString("fn");
    var f = "/webapp/et/" + s;
        
    if (s.length > 1) {
        window.open(f, "Download");
    }
}`code`

Comment: @ChiSen it would be really very much benefitial for you to ask a new question with this problem in order to let everyone take a look, please consider it.And sorry for late reply I had a problem with my internet connection lately.

Answer (score 0):

You can employ forms based authentication. This is the standard way of handling a user login in asp.net. There are some easy to follow tutorials on the official Asp.net website: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security

Answer (score 0):

donot put the link to that file directly. call an asp page which will read and write the file contents

to it's output stream. All this is done on page_load (sender, event); but before reading or writing the file contents, just check if there is a username or password or user id or whatever in the session variables. if there is nothing such, redirect to login.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET [forms authentication](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/introduction/an-overview-of-forms-authentication-vb) to authenticate the user and after authetication process you can redirect the user to the download page.